# What are practical uses of the "&&" and "||" operators in R?

Tags: r, operators, logical-operators

### Main question

**In what practical programming situations or R "idioms" would you only want to check the first element of each of two vectors for logical comparison? (I.e. disregarding the rest of each vector as in `&&` and `||`.)**

I can see the use of `&` and `|` in R, where they do element-wise logical comparison of two vectors.  But I cannot see a real life practical use of their sibling operators `&&` and `||`.  Can anyone provide a clear example of their use?

The documentation ,`help("&&")`, says:

> The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. 
>   Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. 
>   The longer form is appropriate for
>   programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

The issue for me is the following: I interpret the documentation of `&&` and `||` to say that for logical vectors `x` and `y`, the `&&` and `||` operators only use `x[1]` and `y[1]` to provide a result.

```
> c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) && c(TRUE, FALSE)
[1] TRUE

> c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) && c(FALSE, FALSE)
[1] FALSE

> c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) && c(TRUE, FALSE)
[1] FALSE

> c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) && c(FALSE, FALSE)
[1] FALSE
```

I don't see any "programming control-flow" situations where I would have two logical vectors and I would disregard any values past the first element of each.

It seems that `x && y` acts like `x[1] & y[1]`, and `x || y` acts like `x[1] | y[1]`.

### Benchmarks

Here's a test function that evaluates how often these formulations return the same result using randomly generated logical vectors of different lengths.  This suggests that they are doing the same thing.

```
> test <- function( n, maxl=10 ) {
    foo <- lapply( X=seq_len( n ), FUN=function(i) { 
        x <- runif( n=sample( size=1, maxl ) ) > 0.5
        y <- runif( n=sample( size=1, maxl ) ) > 0.5
        sameres <- all.equal( (x||y), (x[1]|y[1]) )
        sameres
    } )

    table( unlist( foo ) )
}
test( 10000 )
```

Yields:

```
TRUE 
 10000
```

Here's a benchmarking test on which is faster. It start by creating a list of lists, where each of `N` items in `dat` is a list containing two randomly generated logical vectors. Then we apply each of the variants on the same data to see which is faster.

```
library(rbenchmark)
N <- 100
maxl <- 10
dat <- lapply( X=seq_len(N), FUN=function(i) { 
    list( runif( n=sample( size=1, maxl ) ) > 0.5, 
          runif( n=sample( size=1, maxl ) ) > 0.5) } )
benchmark( 
    columns=c("test","replications","relative"),
    lapply(dat, function(L){ L[[1]]    || L[[2]]    } ), 
    lapply(dat, function(L){ L[[1]][1] |  L[[2]][1] } ) 
)
```

Yields the following output (removed the `\n` characters and extra whitespace):

```
                                                test replications relative
2 lapply(dat, function(L) { L[[1]][1] | L[[2]][1] })          100    1.727
1 lapply(dat, function(L) { L[[1]]   || L[[2]]    })          100    1.000
```

Clearly, the `||` formulation is faster than cherry picking the first element of each argument.  But I'm still curious as to why one would need such an operator.

Comment: If the call is to a series of functions concatenated by `&&`, then the first one that is false will terminate the procedure, saving time. Calls to `&` always evaluate all their arguments.

Comment: If you have `c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) && c(TRUE, FALSE)` in an `if` clause, you may want to consider using a different `if` clause.

Comment: This is like asking why C has both `&&`/`||` and `&`/`|`.

Comment: @HongOoi It's a bit different, because in C `&` and `|` are bitwise, in R they are not.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I realise that, but the point is that the operators serve different purposes. One set is for flow control. The other set is for either bitwise operations (in C) or vectorised manipulations (in R).

Comment: @HongOoi: Sure. Still, in R, you an use `&` and `|` for flow control,  assuming you don't need the short-circuit behavior. In C not really. It is not pretty to use it in R, but that's an important difference between R and C. (It is pretty surprising, too, if you learn R after C.)

Comment: On thinking about it some more, a related question is: Why do `&&` and `||` not err or give warning when providing them with non-atomic arguments? (The C operators each do not discard data, whereas these R operators do.) @RichardScriven

Comment: You can always rewrite C code to use `&`/`|` instead of `&&`/`||`. That doesn't mean you should do it (it'll certainly be messy). The same holds in R (albeit slightly less messy). The point is that once you understand what the purposes of these operators are, using them appropriately leads to clearer code.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that there are a couple of reasons, but probably the most important one is the short-circuit behavior. If `a` evaluates to `FALSE` in `a && b`, then `b` is not evaluated. Similarly, if `a` evaluates to `TRUE` in `a || b`, then `b` is not evaluated. This allows writing code like

```
v <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
idx <- 6
if (idx < length(v) && v[[idx]] == 5) {
  foo
} else {
  bar
}
```

Otherwise one needs to write this (maybe) as

```
if (idx < length(v)) {
  if (v[idx] == 5) {
    foo
  } else {
    bar
  }
} else {
  bar
}
```

which is 1) much less readable, and 2) repeats `bar`, which is bad if `bar` is a bigger piece of code.

You cannot use `&` in the `if` condition, because your index would be out of bounds, and this is not allowed for lists in R:

```
if (idx < length(v) & v[[idx]] == 5) {
  foo
} else {
  bar
}
# Error in v[[idx]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Here is a small illustration of the short-circuit behavior:

```
t <- function() { print("t called"); TRUE }
f <- function() { print("f called"); FALSE }

f() && t()
# [1] "f called"
# [1] FALSE
f() & t()
# [1] "f called"
# [1] "t called"
# [1] FALSE

t() || f()
# [1] "t called"
# [1] TRUE
t() | f()
# [1] "t called"
# [1] "f called"
# [1] TRUE
```